# A definite multiple integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^1\int_\sqrt[3]{x}^1 4\cos(y^4)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

What I got was

$\sin(1)x+\cos(x^2) dx$ and now I am stuck.

I suddenly froze. Could someone help me? Haven't done calculus for a long time.

Comment: Why do you need help quickly? Are you at an exam?

Comment: i am studying for finals. it's 4:44 am thats why :)

Comment: It's recommended to type your question rather than uploading an image as you did, that way other people can search for your problem if they have the same question.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind. but whenever i type it out, people always edit it for me. I am not good at wording them!
so i thought it'd be convenient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that this is a definite integral, and hence the result should be a number and not a function.

First, note that the inner integral is quite tough to compute. It's not obvious what an anti-derivative of $\cos(y^4)$ should be. Therefore, it is sometimes convenient to change the order of integration, i.e. in this exercise integrate with respect to $x$ first and then with respect to $y$:

$$
\int_0^1\int_\sqrt[3]{x}^1 4\cos(y^4)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\int_0^{y^3}4\cos(y^4)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy.
$$
All you have to consider here is why the upper and lower bounds of the integrals are as they are. To this end, observe that in the first integral we have $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}\leq y\leq 1$ which is equivalent to $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0\leq x\leq y^3$. Now, this should be an easy task to integrate.

Comment: right that makes it a lot easier. Thank you for your help Stefan, I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: so it becomes sin(1)! is that correct?

Comment: @ActuallyanActuary: Indeed.

Comment: thanks a lot! much love from new york!